# HTML email using YAML

Tags: javascript, html, yaml, nodemailer

Our project uses YAML to store plain text email templates.
Here is an example:

```
subject: some subject
body: |
  Hello {firstName} {lastName},

   You have been invited to our App.

   Best Regards,
   App Team
```

Then it parses to `mailParams` and sends to the **nodemailer**.
I got the task to send HTML email but have no idea how...

Can I put HTML code into the YAML somehow or I should work with nodemailer?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with nodemailer message, `html` property

https://nodemailer.com/message/

*html - The HTML version of the message as an Unicode string, Buffer, Stream or an attachment-like object ({path: ‘http://…'})*